# Find the number of ways you can put fruits into drawers

Tags: combinatorics

We have 5 fruits and 3 drawers. I need to find the number of ways I can put the fruits in them when there will be at least one fruit in the lowest drawer and the first and the second fruit won't be in the same drawer.

I tried to do it by the complementary way, I took all of the options $3^5$ and subtruct from it the bad options($2^5$ when there is no fruits in the lowest and $3^4$ when the first and the second are in the same drawer  )

I got to  $3^5-2^5-3^4 =130$ but the answer is 146.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably double counted when there is no fruit in the lowest drawer and when the first and the second fruit are together

Comment: Review the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Answer (score 0):

You subtracted twice when *both* the last drawer is empty *and* the first and the second fruit are together, that happens exactly 16 times which is the error between your answer and the correct answer.

In general you found number of elements of $A$ and of $B$ in order to find the number of elements of $A\cup B$ you need to add the number of elements of $A$ and $B$ and subtract the number of elements of $A\cap B$

$|A\cup B|$ = $|A|$ + $|B|$ - $|A\cap B|$

Answer (score 0):

5 fruit in any of 3 drawers.

$3^5$

Fruit 2 not in the same drawer as fruit 1

$3^4\cdot 2=162$

minus the cases where all of the fruit are in the top two drawers.

$-2^4\cdot 1=16$

$162-16 = 146$

Comment: It seems to me that the count of how many ways you could distribute five pieces of fruit to any of three drawers is superfluous to your argument.

Comment: It is.  But that is where the OP started from, and I wanted to show that it is not part of the solution.